# if: Expression Syntax

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I am trying to execute the below command in Linux. I am getting the error "if: Expression Syntax".

```
$ ssh insite@3.7.25.37 "if [ -f /export/home/insite/.insiteINFO ] ; then echo "1" ; else echo "0" ; fi"
if: Expression Syntax.
```

Comment: Note that your attempted use of nested double-quotes is not advisable. They don't actually nest as you expect.

Comment: If  the answer below solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

That's the result you got if the shell for the insite user was csh or tcsh:

```
$ csh
$ if [ -f /export/home/insite/.insiteINFO ] ; then echo "1" ; else echo "0" ; fi
if: Expression Syntax.
then: Command not found.
else?
```

Try wrapping the test in /bin/sh:

```
$ /bin/sh -c 'if [ -f /export/home/insite/.insiteINFO ] ; then echo "1" ; else echo "0" ; fi'
0
```